# mysql return nested json_objects as json data from select

Tags: mysql, json

Within a mySQL select statement I am creating json objects with `json_object()` and `json_arrayagg()`.
The output returns the json_arrayagg as string with escaped json objects. I would like to have the output directly formatted as json data. I tried to do several modifications but none worked so far.

I need the modification to happen directly in the mySQL statement, not in post-processing with any server code (eg. php) afterwards.

Current example output:

```
{title: "MY_ASSET", id: "a_1", owners: "[{\"id\": \"u_1\", \"username\": \"john\"}]"},
{title: "OTHER_ASSET", id: "a_2", owners: null}
```

Desired output:

```
{title: "MY_ASSET", id: "a_1", owners: [{"id": "u_1", "username": "john"}]},
{title: "OTHER_ASSET", id: "a_2", owners: []}
```

Here is the sql statement I am using:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.title,
    a_owners.owners
    FROM assets AS a
    
    LEFT JOIN 
      (
        SELECT
        a.id,
        json_arrayagg(json_object(
          'id', ua.user_id,
          'username', u.username
        )) 'owners'
        FROM assets AS a
        INNER JOIN user_assets AS ua
        ON a.id=ua.asset_id
        LEFT JOIN `users` AS u
        ON ua.user_id=u.id
        WHERE ua.user_role IN ('owner')
        GROUP BY a.id
    ) AS a_owners
    ON a_owners.id = a.id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you were using to generate the top-level json object with, since your query returned a result set and not the single json object. Anyway, the query done in the following way on a test database using MySQL v.8.0.29 gets the correct result.

You can verify this by copying the code below into the online editor at the following link https://www.mycompiler.io/it/new/mysql.

```
-- Create users table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

-- Insert some sample data into users table
INSERT INTO users (id, username) VALUES
(1, 'user1'),
(2, 'user2'),
(3, 'user3');

-- Create assets table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS assets (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

-- Insert some sample data into assets table
INSERT INTO assets (id, title) VALUES
(1, 'asset1'),
(2, 'asset2'),
(3, 'asset3');

-- Create user_assets table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_assets (
    user_id INT,
    asset_id INT,
    user_role VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, asset_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (asset_id) REFERENCES assets(id)
);

-- Insert some sample data into user_assets table
INSERT INTO user_assets (user_id, asset_id, user_role) VALUES
(1, 1, 'owner'),
(2, 1, 'viewer'),
(2, 2, 'owner'),
(3, 3, 'owner');

-- Execute query
SELECT json_object(
    'id', a.id,
    'title', a.title,
    'owners', a_owners.owners
    ) as 'result'
    FROM assets AS a
    LEFT JOIN 
      (
        SELECT
        a.id,
        json_arrayagg(json_object(
          'id', ua.user_id,
          'username', u.username
        )) 'owners'
        FROM assets AS a
        INNER JOIN user_assets AS ua
        ON a.id=ua.asset_id
        LEFT JOIN `users` AS u
        ON ua.user_id=u.id
        WHERE ua.user_role IN ('owner')
        GROUP BY a.id
    ) AS a_owners
    ON a_owners.id = a.id
```